# How to implement android filterview with having tabs with multiple filter items

Tags: android

i'm developing an android app which requires filter option to sort the list of peoples according to filter values.

Here is i attached my required screen :

**Required Filter Implementation Screen**

[image: Required Filter Implementation Screen]

I tried with Filter Adapter View like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <adapterFilter.AdapterFilterView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            app:filterView_default_filter="Date" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#e4e4e4" />

        <adapterFilter.AdapterFilterView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            app:filterView_default_filter="Relation" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#e4e4e4" />

        <adapterFilter.AdapterFilterView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            app:filterView_default_filter="Status" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and also in this i can choose multiple select filter items also required.
But i'm not able to get the exact design for how to implement this scenario. please help me .. all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad to answer in a timely manner. First you have to decide on what architecture you are going to use for the logic for your tabs. I would suggest implementing each tab inside it's own fragment and implement toolbar options behaviour using `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and method `onOptionsItemSelected`. Then just perform a filter on a list with the items you're displaying and update your `RecyclerView` or `ListView` depending on which you're going to use.